# pandas.read_excel how to get rid of spaces of columns name

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I'm importing a excel file into python with `pd.read_excel()`
The columns names in the file like this :

```
columns_name_xlsx = ['Date:', 'Heure:','P1 (W)', 'P2 (W)', 'P3 (W)']
```

I would like to get :

```
columns_name_expected = ['date:', 'heure:','p1_(w)', 'p2_(w)', 'p3_(w)']
```

I tried with :

```
df.rename(str.lower.replace(' ', '_'), axis='columns')
```

But it does not work. Does sb have an idea ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 2):

```
df.columns = (x.lower().replace(' ', '_') for x in df.columns)
```

Answer (score 1):

Your solution does not work because

1. You are trying to chain two methods which is not really possible
2. The replace methods requires to provide arguments (`' '` and `_`)

Assuming this DataFrame exists

```py
# Build mock dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Date:', 'Heure:', 'P1 (W)', 'P2 (W)', 'P3 (W)'])
```

The simplest method is to iteratively apply a transformation on the initial column name as such

```
df1 = df.rename(columns={v: v.lower().replace(' ', '_') for v in df.columns})
```

Alternatively, you could chain operations and build a custom function

```
df1 = df.rename(str.lower, axis=1).rename(lambda x: x.replace(' ', '_'), axis=1)
```

I hope that helps!